# Aerostats in the outer solar system

Tags: titan, pressure, habitat

Having read a lot lately about some preliminary studies of aerostat options on Venus and Earth (Semirigid gas bags filled with N2/O2 to allow for a dual breathable/lifting gas - sorry no source on that one, maybe I just dreamt it), I have been pondering the options for aerostats further out in the solar system.
Given that all the large bodies have winds too fast to allow for this, would a N2/O2 lifting gas be feasible on Titan, the moon of Saturn:

An article on AGU titled "Titan's Atmosphere and Climate, by Horst, S.M., states that "Infrared spectra taken by the Voyager spacecraft revealed the presence of a variety of organic molecules (C2H2, C2H4, C2H6, C3H8, CH3C2H, C4H2, etc.)"
My main two problems are of oxygen manufacturing and floatation.
The floatation is easy enough, but oxygen is only found in the "mantle" of Titan, int eh form of water.
Given a pressure at sea level of about 150% of Earth, and a gravity of .138g, what are the **calculations** needed to figure out buoyance of a rigid body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what are the calculations needed to figure out buoyance of a rigid body

The bouyant force is just $\rho V g$ where:

- $\rho$ = density of the displaced fluid
- $g$ = local acceleration of gravity
- $V$ = volume of displaced fluid

If the weight of the object is equal to the bouyant force, it floats at a constant depth. Weight greater, it sinks; weight lesser, it rises.